# Cloud Firestore Database is not displaying users after authentication?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do authentication using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` .The user iis getting created since I can signin using the email and password which created using createUserWithEmailAndPassword .But my firestore database is not showing the document which I have created using createUserWithEmailAndPassword().

This is my code:

```
onPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final newuser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
                          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: email ?? 'error',
                        password: password ?? 'error',
                      );
                    
                      if (newuser != null) {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home()),
                        );
                      }
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                    }
```

I have created 3 users with this method and I'm able to login with these credential but these users are not showing in my Firestore Database.
[image: database]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ashish already mentioned, you need to store all your extra parameters in the firestore as documents. A better way to implement this is to use different function to register user and create a user document related to that registered user.

Below is an example I created to help out!

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  String email = "test@test.com";
  String password = "123456";
  String firstName = "test";
  String lastName = "test";
  String phoneNumber = "09876543456";

  /// This is the function to create new user
  Future<void> createUser(
    email,
    password,
    firstName,
    lastName,
    phoneNumber,
    /*... and any other params you wish to collect */
  ) async {
    // firebase auth
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

    // firestore db
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

    // try-catch creation process to accurate exception
    try {
      final credential = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email,
        password: password,
      );

      // get user id
      String userID = credential.user!.uid;

      // creating user profile on db
      await db.collection("users").doc(userID).set({
        "id": userID,
        "firstName": firstName,
        "lastName": lastName,
        "phoneNumber": phoneNumber,
        // ... other params
      });

      print("Signed up successfully!");
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
      print("Something is wrong: $error");
    }
  }

  /// this is the create button
  TextButton(
    onPressed: () async {
      await createUser(
        email,
        password,
        firstName,
        lastName,
        phoneNumber,
        /*... and any other params you wish to collect */
      );
    },
    child: const Text("Create test user"),
  );
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else :). BYE!!!

Answer (score 2):

To store the data in the database you need to use a Firestore instance to store data in firebase Firestore.

```
onPressed: () async {
    try {
      final newuser = await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email ?? 'error',
        password: password ?? 'error',
      );
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users').doc(newuser!.uid).set({
        email: newuser.email
      });
      if (newuser != null) {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => home()),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
}
```

You need to put the data which you want to store in firestore in `set()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication data are show into the login into firebase then on tap of Authentication options menu -> user section , you can view store 3 users data in this section